# How to create a shared partition between Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, shared-folders

I had read this [how-to manual](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35807/how-to-harmonize-your-dual-boot-setup-for-windows-and-ubuntu/), however, I'm not sure how to proceed with my partitions. Here is a list of my partitions: [image: My partitions]

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 8):

That huge unallocated space you have is perfect for enlarging your existing extended partition. Since Ubuntu can interact with NTFS (Windows) partitions, but Windows cannot interact with EXT4 (Linux) partitions, your best option is to create an NTFS partition in that free space.

First click `/dev/sda4` and drag it to the right, then create another partition inside the free space.

Windows allows you to change the location of certain user folders, such as Downloads, Documents, Music, etc. You can do that from each folder's Properties. It would help with integration to change their locations to somewhere on the data partition.

You can then follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772550/making-files-on-windows-10-partition-native-to-ubuntu-partition/772555#772555) to setup up shortcuts from Ubuntu to the corresponding directories on the data partition.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help me.  I got a problem here: I have already 4 partitions, so I can create a new partition. And, I don't know what to do with that. =/

Comment: @IvánCastro - You can create an "extended" partition.

Comment: he already has the extended partition, but it's too small. So just resize it to the end of the drive and create a *logical* partition on that. This is one limitation of gparted because other professional partitioners automatically resize extended partition and avoid moving data as much as possible

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to access the windows drive from ubuntu (unless windows is only hibernated, then it's locked) therefore the easiest way is simply to store your personal data on the windows partition..
Downloads folder is configured in Web browser, documents in any office app you use...so it shouldn't require setting anything in the system

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way it to just use a file system that both OSes can read natively.  NTFS and fat32 are the two primary choices.  The partition then should be available for mounting in both OSes.

Comment: FAT32 can't be larger than 4GB, I think.

Comment: NTFS is the best option

Comment: @Zacharee1 - it can be larger, though **a single file** larger than 4GB can't exist on FAT32

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, Ubuntu is able to read your windows (NTFS format) partition just fine, except if it has been locked by windows (windows does that when it hibernates).

As of now, your best alternative is to have another NTFS partition for storing files you intend to use on both OSes. That "unallocated" space in your hard drive is perfect size for that. Click that, then "Add" and GPARTED will guide you through the process. IF you run into a problem (most likely you won't) regarding number of partitions: click on your /dev/sda4 partition, and resize it to the the maximum amount of space. The "unallocated" space will now be inside of that "extended" partition, and you'll be able to create a NTFS partition in there (following the previous steps).

I must point out that your Ubuntu installation is very small, and will run out of space quite easily. Considering you have plenty of free space, you should extend you ubuntu partitions a bit (or a lot). This should be done before you use up your unallocated space.

Your sda5 is where software will be installed, and sda6 is where your personal files are stored (eg. your Download folder - mine tends to get huge in little time). Resizing these partitions is easy and well documented here in askubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your disk is formatted in MBR mode, and as such can only use 4 partitions, so you can't use your unallocated disk space for a new shared partition. Your Windows partition is large enough, but your Ubuntu partition is tiny. I'd recommend extending your Ubuntu partition to use up all of your unallocated space. In Windows, be sure to turn off FAST BOOT and/or HIBERNATE, or you'll corrupt Windows if/when you mount the Windows partition whilst in Ubuntu. Then edit your Ubuntu FSTAB file to mount the Windows partition when booting Ubuntu, and you'll have your shared disk space. Just place your shared files into your user folder in the Windows partition. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this on your Linux without doing anything on your Windows. If you have already created the shared partition via Windows before, delete the partition and follow these steps.

1. On your Linux app list search bar. Type Disks
2. Click Disks from the app list
3. On the left menu select a storage device (Hard Disk) you want to partition
4. On the main page select one of the storage volume you want to resize.
5. Click the settings button below the volumes bar
6. Click resize...
7. Reduce the partition size to create free space
8. Click Resize
9. On the storage volumes bar, select the new space you just created
10. Click the plus button below the volumes bar to create a partition
11. Click Next to proceed
12. Enter volume name (e.g ShareVolume)
13. Select type as For use with all systems and devices (FAT)
14. Click Create
15. Restart your system and you are done.

For video reference watch https://youtu.be/NtlXZSHL6NE