# Need to Partition Second Hard Drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

Thanks to the help here: [New build want to install Windows 10 and Ubuntu Dual boot on M.2 drive with Sata HDD for storage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060126/new-build-want-to-install-windows-10-and-ubuntu-dual-boot-on-m-2-drive-with-sata), I now have a dual boot PC!

I have a couple of questions regarding the second hard disk.

During the system installs I disconnected the second drive to prevent any possibility of installing to the wrong drive.

Now that the dual boot install in complete I reconnected it, it's working fine but is listed as "sda" while the boot drive is "sdb" will that cause any problems?

Also I'm still slightly confused as to whether I have to partition this second drive for Windows and Ubuntu respectively?

Obviously word files can be read by both OSes and so it would make sense to have only one copy. So I'd prefer not to partition and hence end up with two copies of the file if possible. Is is OK to have one copy that is accessed by both OS on the second hard drive?

Comment: There is no need to partition it, if all works as is (presumably with ntfs). It also doesn't matter if the device is sdb or sda.

Comment: There are at least two different questions here. Please ask only one question at a time. The second (about partitioning and sharing files) is a duplicate of [How to create a shared partition between Ubuntu and Windows](https://askubuntu.com/q/773460/301745) or [Which file system do I select for sharing files between Windows and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/239320/301745)